# How to make a transparent activity using AppCompat

Tags: android, transparent

I have 2 activity 1 is main and other is for showing an image over all other activities My main activity is using this theme

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
</style>
```

and My Image activity is using this theme

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Translucent">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
</style>
```

thing is its showing exactly what i wan on some devices showing the background of other activity but in some devices its showing the background of homescreen

[image]

this is where its showing background of home screen

[image]

this is where its showing my activity background

I am stuck with this problem for quite few long any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `Toolbar` or a custom toolbar, try set color background to transparent (#00000000). It works fine with me. Good luck!